# How to list files of a directory in an other server using ssh2

Tags: php, ssh

I would like to list the files of a directory in an other server

I am connected to an other server using ssh2_connect function the connection is going well and I am able to fetch a desired file but I am not sure how the files can be listed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [ssh2_sftp](http://php.net/ssh2_sftp) and [opendir](http://php.net/opendir), like this:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$sftp_fd = intval($sftp);

$handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp_fd/path/to/directory");
echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
echo "Entries:\n";
while (false != ($entry = readdir($handle))){
    echo "$entry\n";
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to identify if its a file or a directory? especially when a file has no extension name?

Comment: Wow. Really hack method.
In addition, you can use many other filesystem functions by similiar way, e.g scandir, fopen, file_exists, file_get_contents.

Comment: This actually throws the same segmentation fault under PHP 5.6. You really need to pass the `$sftp` resource returned by `ssh2_sftp` through a `intval` first, before concatenating it with anything, as stated by @pcs' answer.

Comment: @VictorSchröder thanks for the notice.
Next time, please update the answer. ;-)

Comment: @elias, sure I should have done it... down vote removed, btw

Comment: the intval helped a different sftp problem

Comment: I struggled to figure out why this solution isn't working... I found out that the path plays a huge role. Start with listing the home directory with "/." like this: $handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}/.");

Comment: If you need to get the contents of a root directory, use `/./` as the path, eg. `opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp_fd/./")`. I struggled with it for some time because there was no error message and I found an answer in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16238476/1743367 . Sharing here in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Comment: And one more comment. This code `while (false != ($entry = readdir($handle)))` is not a correct way to loop over a directory. There should be two equal signs (`!==`), otherwise a directory entry whose name evaluates to FALSE will stop the loop (e.g. a directory named "0"). (more info in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php )

Comment: @Jimmy.B [`ssh2_sftp_stat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp-stat.php) can be used to determine file size, timestamps, permissions, ownership etc. The `'mode'` element can be used to distinguish between file/directory/link/etc.

Answer (score 25):

In case anybody is struggling to get this to work, and you are running `PHP 5.6.28` there was a recent update that either created a requirement or introduced a bug where `intval()` must be used on each SFTP folder/file access function:

```
$handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."/path/to/directory");
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! I kept getting segfaults since that PHP update!

Comment: Why is this not the top answer?

Comment: Thank you! Day also saved for me.

Comment: I note that this problem seems to be continuing with php7. The suggested workaround above is also not doing anything for me. In fact, I am bewildered as to whether casting a value to an integer before reconstructing it into a string could have an effect anyway? The argument being passed to the opendir function would surely be the same in both cases (unless something spooky is happening at the low levels?)
Strangely, sometimes I get "bus error - core dumped" and in another implementation, "segmentation fault - core dumped". The function does still return a valid response however?

Comment: @GordonRouse ending with `closedir($handle);` solves your issue? it works for me.

Comment: @yceruto - yes, that does help!

Comment: Thank you. I recently had to modify working code that I developed a year ago and I kept getting an error indicating the path did not exist when using scandir(). This was the solution and it applies to my current version which is `PHP 5.6.40`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method which can scan directories recursively and return multi-dimensional arrays if the recursive parameter is set, or only scan the path and return a single dimension array containing files in that directory if it's not. Can be modified to also include directories without contents in non-recursive mode if needed.

Creating it as a class makes it easy to be reused later. I only included the methods from my class that were required to answer the question.

```
$host      = 'example.com';
$port      = 22;
$username  = 'user1';
$password  = 'password123';
$path      = '.';
$recursive = true;

$conn = new SFTP($host, $port);
$conn->login($username, $password);
$files = $conn->ls($path, $recursive);
var_dump($files);

class SFTP
{
  private $connection;
  private $sftp;

  public function __construct($host, $port = 22)
  {
    $this->connection = @ssh2_connect($host, $port);
    if (! $this->connection)
      throw new Exception("Could not connect to $host on port $port.");
  }

  public function login($username, $password)
  {
    if (! @ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $username, $password))
      throw new Exception("Could not authenticate with username $username");
    $this->sftp = @ssh2_sftp($this->connection);
    if (! $this->sftp)
      throw new Exception("Could not initialize SFTP subsystem.");
  }

  public function ls($remote_path, $recursive = false)
  {
    $tmp      = $this->sftp;
    $sftp     = intval($tmp);
    $dir      = "ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$remote_path";
    $contents = array();
    $handle   = opendir($dir);

    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
      if (substr("$file", 0, 1) != "."){
        if (is_dir("$dir/$file")){
          if ($recursive) {
            $contents[$file] = array();
            $contents[$file] = $this->ls("$remote_path/$file", $recursive);
          }
        } else {
          $contents[] = $file;
        }
      }
    }

    closedir($handle);
    return $contents;
  }
}
```

Comment: a useful class! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

You give it the `ls` command, assuming it is a UNIX-based system (usually the case), otherwise the OP-specific command like `dir` for Windows.

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'ls');
?>
```

Comment: `ls` don't help if you want to loop through the directory entries. Also, it won't work if the host only allows the SFTP subsytem and deny shell access.

Comment: This was my first idea but, what happen when you don´t have acces to execute command by sftp? then this answer do not work.

Answer (score 0):

late to the party but found this on packagist, https://phpseclib.com/docs/sftp

edit: after installing with

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0
```

here's a sample script:

```
<?php

use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../vendor/autoload.php');

$remote_user = getenv('REMOTE_USERNAME');
$remote_pass = getenv('REMOTE_PASSWORD');
$sftp = new SFTP('remote_server.example.com');
$sftp->login($user, $pass);

$path = '/somepath_to_files';

$rawlist = $sftp->rawlist($path, true);

if (!empty($rawlist)) {
    foreach ($rawlist as $file) {
        if (!empty($file)) {
            $dt_utc = new DateTimeImmutable(date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $file->mtime));
            $dt_nyc = $dt_utc->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
            echo "file: " . $file->filename . " with create time of " .
                $dt_nyc->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "\n";
        }
    }
} else {
    // there's an empty directory
}

echo "end of list \n";
```

Comment: this answer would be improved by showing how to use it to solve this problem