# PHP is_dir() not working as expected over SFTP

Tags: php, sftp

I am running this code on Linux to recursively copy files from a directory.
The echo statement 'FOUND A DIR!' never prints out.  I have also tried is_dir(realpath($file)) and that doesn't work either. Also tried is_dir($path . / . $file). No luck.  Any other suggestions?

```
<?php 

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

/* Remote directory to get */
$remote_dir = '/home/sets';
$local_dir = '/var/www/sets';

// set up connection
$connection = ssh2_connect('1.2.3.4', 22);

//log in with username and password
if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)) throw new Exception('Unable to connect via SSH');

// create SFTP resource
if (!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)) throw new Exception('Unable to connect via SFTP');

// download all of the files in the directory
recursiveScp($remote_dir, $sftp, $connection, $local_dir);  


function recursiveScp($path, $sftp, $connection, $local_dir) {
  $files = scandir('ssh2.sftp://' . intval($sftp) . $path);

  if (!empty($files)) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' 
                && ($file[0] != '.')) { // don't copy over hidden files
                if (is_dir($file))
                {
                     echo ('FOUND A DIR!' . '<br>');
                    // make folder
                    mkdir($local_dir . $file);

                    // recur, adding a / to the path
                    recursiveScp($path . '/',  $sftp, $connection, $local_dir);                             
                }
                else
                {
                    ssh2_scp_recv($connection, "$path/$file", "$local_dir/$file");
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: `is_dir()` works on the local file system, perhapps its not happy with your `'ssh2.sftp://'` source

Comment: From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) for `is_dir()`: Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is a directory, FALSE otherwise. Key word for returning a value of `true` is **exists**. This implies `is_dir()` will only work on the local system.

Comment: Perhaps try looking into using `opendir()` instead of `scandir()`. it's possible that this may behave as expected iterating through the directory handle. eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841276/61795

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24578/is-dir-function-for-ftp-ftps-connections